# $t: X \rightarrow X$ is a map that preserves distances, give an example where $t$ is not bijective

Tags: metric-spaces, isometry

Let $X$ be a metric space and $t:X \rightarrow X$ a map that preserves distances $d(t(x),t(y))=d(x,y)$. Give an example in which $t$ is not bijective.

I thought every map that preserves distances was isometric and thus bijective? 
In the previous question in my book I had to prove that $t$ was injective, so I know I should find a $t$ that's not surjective.

Comment: One standard example is the (right-)shift operator on $\ell^2$.

Comment: Every map that preserves distances is injective, but not necessarily bijective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $X=\mathbb{N}$ with the discrete metric and the map $f\colon \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$, $f(n)=n+1$.